# How to use turf.js with ionic?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, mapbox, turfjs

I am new to ionic and trying to use [turf](http://turfjs.org/) in ionic app. 
First i installed it via npm using

```
npm install turf
```

This added turf folder in node modules. I copied this in lib folder.
Then i added link to turf.min.js in index page.

Its giving this error

```
turf.featurecollection is not a function
```

Code used -

```
  var features = [
            turf.point([-97.502754, 35.463455], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.508269, 35.463245], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.516809, 35.465779], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.515372, 35.467072], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.509363, 35.463053], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.511123, 35.466601], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.518547, 35.469327], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.519706, 35.469659], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.517839, 35.466998], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.508678, 35.464942], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            }),
            turf.point([-97.514914, 35.463453], {
                "marker-color": "#6BC65F",
                "title": "Too Far",
                "marker-size": "small"
            })
        ];

        var fc = turf.featurecollection(features);

        var nearest = turf.nearest(point, fc);

        nearest.properties["marker-color"] = "#25561F";
        nearest.properties["title"] = "Nearest Point";
        nearest.properties["marker-size"] = "large";
        nearest.properties["marker-symbol"] = "star-stroked";

        var nearest_fc = turf.featurecollection([point, nearest]);

        var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'charuoshan.0n1b363n')
            .setView([35.463453, -97.508014], 14);

        L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(fc).addTo(map);
        L.mapbox.featureLayer().setGeoJSON(nearest_fc).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a simple typo. It should be [`featureCollection`](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-helpers/index.js#L150-L155).